# Proof that the following integer multiplication is well defined

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that multiplication given by 
$[(a,b)][(c,d)] = [(ac + bd,ad + bc)]$ is well defined.

My work:

$(a,b) \sim (a_1,b_1) \rightarrow a + b_1 = a_1 + b$

$(c,d) \sim (c_1,d_1) \rightarrow c + d_1 = c_1 + d$

I want to show that $(ac + bd,ad + bc) \sim (a_1c_1 + b_1d_1,a_1d_1 + b_1c_1)$, however I can't seem to get it no matter how I try it if someone could explain.

Answer (score 2):

Try breaking in up into two pieces
$$
(ac+bd, ad+bc) \sim (a_1c+b_1d, a_1d+b_1c) \sim  (a_1c_2+b_1d_1, a_1d_2+b_1c_1) 
$$
For the first, note that $a+b_1 = a_1 + b$ implies both $ac+b_1c = a_1c + bc$ and $ad+b_1d = a_1d + bd$.  Putting these together gives $ac+bd+a_1d+b_1c = ad+bc+a_1c+b_1d$, as desired.  Getting the second equivalence is similar.

Comment: Thanks Rolf, I am a newbie and followed your work.

Comment: I couldn't follow what $c_2$ and $d_2$ is... I mean what does subscript $2$ denote?